# Ajax web api File Upload With Progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying out this code to upload file to the server,

**Html:**

```
<input type="file" id="file1" name="browsefile" multiple="multiple"  accept="video/mp4,video/*">
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function FileUpload(SomestringParameter) {
    var files = $("#file1").get(0).files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
        if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
            var data = new FormData();
            for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:50443/UploadFile/" + SomestringParameter,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (results) {
                alert(results);
                for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    alert(results[i]);
                }
            }
        });

    } 
    else {
        alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 multiple file uploads!");
    }
}
}
```

**In Web Api Controller**,

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("UploadFile")]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile([FromRoute]string SomeStringData)
{
    // Save the uploaded file here on the server
}
```

The File is uploaded perfectly, My question is how to show progress bar, I'm using jquery mobile for designing.

**How could I show a progress bar with percentage or something?**

Comment: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [blueimp's jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) ? I have used it in few of my projects and it does provide you a progress bar along with a host of other features that you would love to have in a file upload.

The basic version (and all other version too) has a progress bar for file upload. You can check out a [demo](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html).

[image]

This plugin also allows you to modify the progress bar and related information by exposing the `fileuploadprogress` function - [Read Documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Extended-progress-information)

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadprogress', function (e, data) {
    // Log the current bitrate for this upload:
    console.log(data.bitrate);
});
```

This plugin uses [Bootstrap's progress bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress) component to display its progress bar.

What's better is that it provides a [documented integration](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki#aspnet) with ASP.NET and there's a [github project](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) for how to use this plugin with [ASP.NET MVC](https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3) too.

Hope this helps you.